# How to limit the amount of words across multiple textareas?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Word Limit of 300 Words on 4 textareas on whole i.e. word count of 4 textareas should not cross 300 on whole. How can I achieve this, although I have gone through many articles on this, which show only on single textarea.

Comment: What method works for you best on the single textarea. It would probably be easier to modify it to work for multiple textareas than create/search new solutions.

Comment: 300 words, or 300 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be an option i guess. Just change `limit` to your desired need e.g **300**. I left it at **3** for testing purpose. The good thing is that this way we are not disabling the `keyup` event handler, if we exceed the `limit` the words get cut off the `textarea` by using `substr` with the current `value.length -1`. So for example if i type 3 words in the first `textarea` and the limit is reached, i can still delete one word from the first `textarea` and type it into the second `textarea`, which would not be possible if we `return false` after `limit` is reached. To detect copy/paste actions i have added the `paste` listener and check if we've reached the limit to omit pasting more words than the actual limit of words. But pasting is still possible even across the `textareas`.

```js
$(function () {

  var total = 0,
      limit = 3,
      $textArea = $('textarea');

  function addToTotal(collection, pastedWordCount) {
    var wordCount = 0;
    $textArea.each(function(index, element) {
      if (!!element.value.match(/\S+/g)) {
        wordCount += element.value.match(/\S+/g).length;
      }
    });
    if (pastedWordCount !== undefined && pastedWordCount !== 0) {
      wordCount = pastedWordCount;
    }
    return wordCount;
  }

  $textArea.on("keyup", function () {
    total = addToTotal($textArea);
    if (total > limit) {
      this.value = this.value.substr(0, this.value.length -1);
    }
  });

  $textArea.on("paste", function (evt) {
    var pasteDataWordCount = 0;
    if (!!evt.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text').match(/\S+/g)) {
      pasteDataWordCount = evt.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text').match(/\S+/g).length; 
    }
    total += addToTotal($textArea, pasteDataWordCount);
    if (total > limit) {
      return false;
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="" id="text1" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<textarea name="" id="text2" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<textarea name="" id="text3" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<textarea name="" id="text4" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: How to check Copy & Paste counts..??

Comment: @Shaan_14 Did you check my answer?

Comment: @Praveen Kumar Really like your solution, especially for being so compact. Your limit is off by plus one character though.

Comment: @ Praveen: I checked your answer & I agree with DavidDomain

Answer (score 1):

**Update: Word Count, instead of char count!**

> Beware, this code doesn't check the copy paste counts. For this:
>
> 1. Either I have to disable copy paste. (Functionality Loss)
> 2. Or I should trim off the text after paste. (Data Loss)

I don't understand why this should be a problem. You can try this:

```js
$(function () {
  $("textarea").keydown(function () {
    val = 0;
    $("textarea").each(function () {
      if ($(this).val().trim().length > 0)
        val += $(this).val().trim().replace(/\s+/gi, ' ').split(' ').length  ;
    });
    if (val > 300)
      return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="" id="text1" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<textarea name="" id="text2" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<textarea name="" id="text3" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<textarea name="" id="text4" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: You should really re-read the question. They want to prevent the **combined** word count of *all* `<textarea>` elements from passing 300.

Comment: @PraveenKumar 300 not 400. ;-)

Comment: @Praveen: Well Above counts the number of characters in textareas.

Comment: Words! @Shaan_14 Just saw it.

Comment: @Shaan_14 Can you chekc now!

Answer (score 0):

1) This can be achieved by declaring a global variable which keeps the count of the words in all the three text areas.

2) Onkeyup event of each text area increment the global variable declared and check the current value.if it is less than 400 allow to enter else alert or do the action as required

check the following sample

```
            <html>
        <script>
        var globalCount=0;
        function fun1(){
                globalCount=document.getElementById("text1").value.length+document.getElementById("text2").value.length+document.getElementById("text3").value.length+document.getElementById("text4").value.length
                if(globalCount>=400){
                alert("max word count reached");
                //do what needs to be done 
                }

        }

        </script>
        <body>
          <textarea name="t1" id="text1" cols="30" rows="10"  onkeyup="fun1()"></textarea>
          <textarea name="t2" id="text2" cols="30" rows="10"  onkeyup="fun1()"></textarea>
          <textarea name="t3" id="text3" cols="30" rows="10"  onkeyup="fun1()"></textarea>
          <textarea name="t4" id="text4" cols="30" rows="10" onkeyup="fun1()"></textarea>
             </body>
    </html>
```